# How to make sure, that a page has been viewed for X seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

in my project users can view specific pages to receive a little bonus. When they are on the site where they can select bonuses, an iframe of the page is shown with a countdown. Once the countdown is over, they can click the "Get reward button".
Once they did this, an ajax call is sent to claim_rewards.php.

However, there are a few problems:
An a little bit more experienced user could call the claim_rewards.php without the need of viewing the iframe page for X seconds. He selects a reward, browses other sites and once the time is over, calls claim_rewards.php. It's already made that the request only is valid after the X seconds. But still, the user could do other things in the mean time.

What would be the best approach to make sure, that a user only gets the reward, when he really watched the iframe for X seconds?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Yes, sure. The first thing was to make a time claiming limit. The user can call the ajax request but won't get rewarded before X time is over. Other ideas I am trying to get here :D

Comment: You could have 3 buttons, numbered 1-3. In the middle of the X seconds, a message pops up saying press '2' to claim your reward.

Comment: How do you technically define "they are on the site"? Without every user having a webcam tracking them and their display.

Comment: The user has to actively view the page, then he is an active user.

If I do it with the buttons, a more experienced user can see this and display the buttons before the countdown runs out.

Comment: I should have written "**technically**" in bold.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a unique token for each visitor

2) Start the timer on the server side and save the start timestamp along with a token

3) Start the timer on the client side to make the button appear.

4) When a user sends the query to claim bonus, send back the token and check the difference between server timer and request time.

Comment: 1) how can that be done without the user seeing the token for example in the cookie or source code (javascript)? 
2) It's already solved
3) Also solved
4) Also solved
As I wrote, an experience user browses other sites and once the time X is over, he calls the request and will get the reward. But I want to accomplish, that only real views count.

Comment: That does not matter if the user sees the token or not. You need to check the validity on the server side. User can manipulate the page as much as he wants. Your job is to check if he is passing valid requests. Keep the "flow" state on server side and you will be fine!

Comment: Other way to accomplish it is to make a new request for the refresh token when X seconds is passed from Iframe. Then pass your refresh token along with access token to the server.